# How to populate the array of events in fullCalendar?

Tags: php, arrays, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullCalendar plugin. I just want to ask how to populate the events  using for loop.

In here, this is done statically by enumerating in the codes the events:

```
var evt = [
{
    title  : primaryAssets[0],
    start  : releaseDates[0],

},
{
    title  : primaryAssets[1],
    start  : releaseDates[1],
}];
```

fullCalendar:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    weekMode: 'liquid',
    weekends: true,

    events: evt
  });
```

This is actually working if I do it this way. I can see these events in the calendar, but I really want to plot them dynamically using for loop. Here i tried using for loop but it only displays the last set of elements of the array:

```
var primaryAssets = <?php echo json_encode($primaryAsset_Array); ?>;

var releaseDates = <?php echo json_encode($releaseDate_Array); ?>;


for(var i = 0;i < count;i++)
{
    var primaryAsset = primaryAssets[i];
    var release_Date = releaseDates[i];

    // array of events
    var getEvent = [];  
    // inserting data from database to getEvent array
    var insertEvents = {};
        insertEvents =
        {
            title: primaryAsset,
            start: release_Date,
        }
    getEvent.push(insertEvents);

}
```

fullCalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
editable: false,
weekends: true, 
events: getEvent

});
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(getEvent); ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting your `getEvent` array on every iteration, as a result your array will only contain one element from last iteration,so move it outside of loop, and it should work fine, like:

```
var getEvent = []; 
for(var i = 0;i < count;i++)
{
    var primaryAsset = primaryAssets[i];
    var release_Date = releaseDates[i];

    // array of events
    //var getEvent = [];  <-- move it out of loop
    // inserting data from database to getEvent array
    var insertEvents = {};
        insertEvents =
        {
            title: primaryAsset,
            start: release_Date,
        }
    getEvent.push(insertEvents);

}
```

Comment: Ah damn! I didn't notice that. Thank you sir Sudhir! It worked!